# Algorithm for text similarity search

Tags: java

say I have String  `x= "algorithm"` , and String`y= "mgth"`

String `x` contains all the letters in String `y`, I can split String `y` into a list of letters, and loop through this list to see if String `x` contains the letter `y[index]` ,, 
but I wonder If there's a more efficient way

Edit:

in kotlin there's a simple intersect function,, for example:

```
val x="algorithm".toList()
val y="mgth".toList()
val interesct=x.intersect(y) //returns a Set of matching chars

if (y.size == interesct.size){
    println("match")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexp for the rescue:

```
    String pattern = "mgth".chars()
            .mapToObj(ch -> "(?=.*" + (char) ch + ")")
            .collect(Collectors.joining());

    // ".*(?=.*m)(?=.*g)(?=.*t)(?=.*h).*"
    boolean matches = Pattern.compile(".*"+pattern+".*")
            .matcher("algorithm")
            .matches();

    System.out.println(matches);
```

This will match only if `"algorithm"` contains all characters in generated pattern  from target string.

**EDIT**

Also, you can sort both strings, and perform comparison only in interval of `[min("mgth"), max("mgth")]` char values.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more efficient way by using a `Set`.

```
String x = "algorithm";
String y = "mgth";
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();

for(char c: y.toCharArray())
   set.add(c);
for(char c: x.toCharArray())
   set.remove(c);

if(set.size() == 0) 
    System.out.println("X contains Y");
else 
    System.out.println("X does not contain Y");
```

What the above code does is add the characters in the smaller `String` to the set. Then, it removes each of the characters in the larger `String`.

If there are any leftover characters in the `Set`, then that means that the smaller `String` contained a letter that was not in the larger `String`.

Comment: Be careful of using `String` instead of character there - you don't actually want a set of `String`.  You could also do `Set<Character> ySet = new HashSet<>(y.toCharArray()); Set<Character> intersection = (new HashSet<>(set)).retainAll(ySet); if (intersection.size <> ySet.size())`

Comment: Actually, the `toCharArray` thing won't work.  It'll produce `List<char[]>`  Probably should use something more like `y.chars().mapToObj(c->(char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
@Test
public void similarity() {
  String x = "algorithm";
  String y = "mgth";
  final boolean ohYes =
      y.chars().filter(yc -> x.chars().anyMatch(xc -> yc == xc)).count() == y.length();
  Assert.assertTrue(ohYes);
}
```

Comment: this will return true if at least one character in X is equal. The question is about all Y characters equation.

Comment: Nope, all characters, see the y.lenght() equality.